# Delete UILocalNotification from iOS Notification Center automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to send UILocalNotifications and delete them automatically after a certain interval from the Notification Center.
My app sends information to users that in about 5 minutes since sending would be irrelevant.
There are going to be at least 3 notifications a day.
Since the information of the notifications would be irrelevant in a few minutes, it would be much better to delete those notifications from Notification Center - because they would be irrelevant to the user.

Is there any way to achieve this? Sort kind of a "self-destruction" option of local notifications?

Thank you!

Comment: there is way but it will delete all notification that are there in UILocalNotification. is that okay?

Comment: @FahimParkar If it's the only way, I guess...
Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is to remove the notifications from the notification centre even without bringing the application to foreground(new notification to clear the old notifications), then the answer is straight forward "NO".

> Without user accepting the older notification or manually brings the
>   application to foreground - It is not possible.

A possibility if this feature may come out with iOS7!

Comment: Did it came out with iOS7?

Comment: @Lapidus No. Thanks & Regards: iOS14